# path to generated contenful middleman data file

Tags: ruby, middleman, contentful

'universal_meganav' is the name of my contentful space. My data folder looks like:

[image]

PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i.yaml is generated by the `contenful_middleman build` command. It contains:

```
---
:id: PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i
:pageTitle: This is a test title
```

How do I access this `:pageTitle:` in my views without relying on the generated file name?

```
<%= data.universal_meganav.homepage %>
```

returns

```
{"PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i"=>{"id"=>"PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i", "pageTitle"=>"This is a test title"}}
```

I was trying `<%= data.universal_meganav.homepage[0] %>` but this isn't working. I've seen examples manipulating the data in config.rb in a loop but I get an error of "NoMethodError: undefined method 'universal_meganav' for nil:NilClass" if I try and access `data.universal_meganav` in config.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the content as a list:

```
<% data.universal_meganav.homepage.each do |_, item| %>
  <h1><%= item.pageTitle %></h1>
  <!-- ... etc ... -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: so the '_' ignores or skips `PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i` ?

Comment: Thanks btw this worked. Curious if there is a way to do it without the loop? This is a pattern I'll need to repeat and in most cases I'll know for certain there is a length of 1

Comment: The _ ignores the ID parameter in the block.

Comment: If you already know the ID, you can access it as a key: `data.universal_meganav.homepage['PCWLCTeTCKsaoGGSQOc6i']`